# Error removing or purging packages

Tags: apt, package-management

I have a problem and I needed Gparted for resizing, after some searching I used a commmand to install Gparted that installed many other packages I don't need, for example 'mines games' 'solitaire game' 'gedit editor' and other apps.

When I run `sudo apt-get remove package-name` or `purge` it gives me this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-software-plugin-snap : Depends: gnome-software (= 3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.8) but it is not going to be installed
 gnome-themes-extra : Depends: gnome-themes-extra-data (>= 3.28-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried running gedit which is one of the apps I want to remove and gives that error, gedit for example works, so some apps installed but cannot `purge` or `remove`

The idea is that I don't want to `fix` these packages, just remove them.

Comment: As the console suggests, try running `sudo apt --fix-broken-install` and post the results here

Comment: The system is trying to tell you about a *version conflict* that you have created. The *dependency chain* is what is broken by incompatible versions. The packages themselves are not corrupted,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gparted is not the reason why the package you mention were installed, that was probably some package are there and installation was pending.

*sudo apt rdepends gparted:*

```
gparted
Reverse Depends:
  Suggests: drobo-utils
 |Suggests: lxqt-config
```

as you can see gparted had only suggested package.

the package mentioned in your post are dependency of gnome core:

*sudo apt rdepends gnome-themes-extra:*

```
gnome-themes-extra
Reverse Depends:
  Depends: gnome-core (>= 3.22)
  Recommends: afterstep
  Depends: materia-gtk-theme
  Recommends: lightdm-gtk-greeter
  Depends: gnome-themes-standard
 |Recommends: cinnamon-core
 |Depends: cinnamon
  Depends: arc-theme
```

And I think you have a broken installation of gnome there. As per @Parto says, run :

```
sudo apt --fix-broken-install
```

In order to satisfy the missing dependency, and after that start to remove packages you want to remove.

Anyway if you want to remove package with apt you have to repair first the unsatisfied dependency, then remove packages.

Suggestion: do not use dpkg to remove package, prefer always apt command or GUI package manager.